# Could not find method id() for arguments [com.google.gms.google-services] || Flutter Firebase

Tags: flutter, firebase, firebase-realtime-database, flutter-layout, flutter-dependencies

I am working on stripe integration where for server side I am using firebase.
I have done many times firebase integration but not able to find the solution of my error.

[image: my error]
as you can see the image the error is showing on line number 73 which is

**id 'com.google.gms.google-services'**

this is my android/app/build.gradle file

```
    def localProperties = new Properties()
def localPropertiesFile = rootProject.file('local.properties')
if (localPropertiesFile.exists()) {
    localPropertiesFile.withReader('UTF-8') { reader ->
        localProperties.load(reader)
    }
}

def flutterRoot = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.sdk')
if (flutterRoot == null) {
    throw new GradleException("Flutter SDK not found. Define location with flutter.sdk in the local.properties file.")
}

def flutterVersionCode = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionCode')
if (flutterVersionCode == null) {
    flutterVersionCode = '1'
}

def flutterVersionName = localProperties.getProperty('flutter.versionName')
if (flutterVersionName == null) {
    flutterVersionName = '1.0'
}

apply plugin: 'com.android.application'
apply plugin: 'kotlin-android'
apply from: "$flutterRoot/packages/flutter_tools/gradle/flutter.gradle"

android {
    compileSdkVersion 32
    ndkVersion flutter.ndkVersion

    compileOptions {
        sourceCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
        targetCompatibility JavaVersion.VERSION_1_8
    }

    kotlinOptions {
        jvmTarget = '1.8'
    }

    sourceSets {
        main.java.srcDirs += 'src/main/kotlin'
    }

    defaultConfig {
        // TODO: Specify your own unique Application ID (https://developer.android.com/studio/build/application-id.html).
        applicationId "com.example.payemnt_ui"
        // You can update the following values to match your application needs.
        // For more information, see: https://docs.flutter.dev/deployment/android#reviewing-the-build-configuration.
        minSdkVersion 21
        targetSdkVersion flutter.targetSdkVersion
        versionCode flutterVersionCode.toInteger()
        versionName flutterVersionName
    }

    buildTypes {
        release {
            // TODO: Add your own signing config for the release build.
            // Signing with the debug keys for now, so `flutter run --release` works.
            signingConfig signingConfigs.debug
        }
    }
}

flutter {
    source '../..'
}

dependencies {
    implementation "org.jetbrains.kotlin:kotlin-stdlib-jdk7:$kotlin_version"
}

id 'com.google.gms.google-services'
```

If i remove this line **id 'com.google.gms.google-services'** app starts working but shows more error after starting of app.I know the problem is with this line only.

Comment: Change this `id 'com.google.gms.google-services'` to this `apply plugin: 'com.google.gms.google-services'`.

Comment: This ^, also make sure you place it in the right place in that file. You should place it next to the other 3 apply statements in your file.

Comment: @Jet.B.Pope and Chance thanks for pointing out my error but in my last project I have used id 'com.google.gms.google-services' in the last line and it was working fine and even in new firebase config they have changed from apply plugin:'com.google.gms.google-services' to id 'com.google.gms.google-services' 

So, why this like so ??

Comment: It's how firebase documentation tells you to do it. Just because it runs okay one time doesn't mean it's the correct way and won't break in the future.

Comment: ya you also got some good point